# Heroku imagemagick brightness parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, paperclip

when I am trying to change brightness of image (paperclip post processing) at heroku via imagemagick with following code:

```
command = "#{File.expand_path(@file.path)} -resize x300^ -brightness-contrast +50 -gravity Center -crop 300x300+0+0 -colorspace Gray #{File.expand_path(dst.path)}"
```

I have following error:

```
convert: unrecognized option `-brightness' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/844.
```

How can I change brightness of image?